# How to let someone test run iOS app on device without revealing code?

Tags: ios

I have created a Universal iOS app and tested it on both iOS Simulator and on my iPad. I have a developer friend who has an iPhone, and has agreed to test run it on his own device. I would like to send the app to him. I was wondering if there is any way to send it without revealing the entire code?

P.S. I have been a registered iOS dev for several years now but haven't yet released any apps. This will be my first one.

Comment: http://testflightapp.com/

Comment: My question is whether the tester on the other end will be able to see my code?

Comment: No, they won't. You'll be sending them an application binary.

Comment: How can I send an app binary? (That is what I am looking for!)

Comment: You could send app binary (*.ipa file) by Email or any other technology for sending files. Your friend will install it on his device by iTunes.

Answer (score 3):

You should read apple's app distribution guide for beta testing.  I have linked to it.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

Answer (score 3):

You should create an `*.ipa` file and send it to your friend and how to create it is give here.

http://bmpradeep.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/how-to-create-an-ipa-file-in-xcode-4-3-or-higher/

you can also check `Testflight`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test app on your friend side but don't show code to him then you need build app on your side and send *.ipa file to your friend. For it you need developer certificate with private key and provisioning profile with your friend's iPhone UDID. If your friend - is owner of developer account then provide to him your app Bundle Id and he will generate provisioning profile for you. The main idea that *.ipa file could be run on device but it doesn't contain source code.